# Is it healthy to consume pumpkin flowers with its vines diseased affected by Squash Bug?

Tags: diseases, flowers, safety, pumpkins, edible

Is it OK to eat flowers of Pumpkins Vines affected by Squash Bug? The vines are dying but not the flowers or Pumpkins, Missouri.